# Call custom shared library from Excel 2016 for mac

Tags: excel, macos

I gather that sandboxing has been added to Excel 2016 add-ins on OSX. This breaks add-ins that have in their header functions coming from a shared library.  As in, something like:

```
Option Explicit
#If Mac Then
Private Declare Function PropsSI_private Lib "libCoolProp.dylib" Alias "PropsSI" (ByVal Output As String, ByVal Name1 As String, ByVal Value1 As Double, ByVal Name2 As String, ByVal Value2 As Double, ByVal Ref As String) As Double
...
```

because at add-in load time, we can't call any functions before the shared library is tried to be loaded.

Previously we just needed to make sure that the correct shared library was in ~/lib, but that no longer works. How do we modify our add-in to allow us to call the shared library?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out the answer is you need to put put the shared library in `/Users/${USER}/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office` and make sure that this folder is added to the system path.  One way to do this is to save save these contents as the file `~/Library/LaunchAgents/my.startup.plist` (obviously replace `ihb` with the appropriate user name)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>my.startup</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>sh</string>
  <string>-c</string>
  <string>launchctl setenv DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH "/Users/ihb/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office"</string>
</array>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```